# Disable submit button on a form until fields completed

Tags: php, forms

I am currently working on a marketing page. It has a form that requires a user to put in their name and their zip code and email address. Once the user does so it will ask them to pick a location close to them for a coupon. The form currently only displays locations if the user fills in their zip code. Otherwise it displays a box telling them to input their zip code. I am struggling trying to get the user to also be required to input an email address as well. I was trying to set my code to display the locations only if both are filled. Here is what I have that I can not get to work.

```
<form id="sportsclips">
                    <div id="return-data"></div>
                    <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" tabindex="1000" maxlength="35" placeholder="Full Name" />
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" tabindex="2000" maxlength="45" placeholder="Email Address *" />
                    <input type="text" id="zipcode" name="zipcode" tabindex="4000" maxlength="5" placeholder="Zip Code *" />                        

                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';zipit(document.getElementById('zipcode').value);" class="coupon" >GET MY COUPON</a>

                    <div id="light" class="white_content">
                    <h1>SELECT A PARTICIPATING LOCATION TO RECEIVE YOUR COUPON</h1>
                    <div class="col-sm-12" style="height: 35px !important;"></div>

                   <div class="col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom: 20px !important;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cls" onclick="document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';">X</a></div>

                   <div id="data"></div>



                    </div>

                    </form>
```

The php that produces the results is below:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['zipcode']) && $_POST['zipcode'] != "" && $_POST['email'] != "" )
{
    # vars
    $country     = 'US';
    $apiKey      = 'AIzaSyA39tPZzpT6KxjVEvmSFV_yWdR7kQvL0zU';
    $latitude    = '';
    $longitude   = '';
    $link        = '';
    $sql         = '';
    $result      = '';
    $earthRadius = '';

    # connect to the google geocode service
    $file = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=".$_POST['zipcode'].",".$country."&amp;output=csv&amp;key=".$apiKey."";

    # load xml
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($file) or die("url not loading");

    # check if status is good
    $status = $xml->status;

    if ($status == "OK") 
    {
            # grab latitude and longitude from zip to match against db
            $latitude = $xml->result->geometry->location->lat;
            $longitude = $xml->result->geometry->location->lng; 

            # Build the spherical geometry SQL string
            $earthRadius = '3963.0'; // In miles

            # db connect if post is true
            $link = mysql_connect('localhost','haircutp_spor7Cl','~=L6QK%%lck-{dZ,Of');

            if(!($link))
            {
                echo "Error Connecting to the Database".mysql_error();
            }
            else 
            {
                mysql_select_db('haircutp_ca_promo');           
            }

            # db call to locations by lat / long
            $sql = "
                SELECT ROUND(
                        ".$earthRadius." * ACOS(  
                            SIN( ".$latitude."*PI()/180 ) * SIN( latitude*PI()/180 )
                            + COS( ".$latitude."*PI()/180 ) * COS( latitude*PI()/180 )  *  COS( (longitude*PI()/180) - (".$longitude."*PI()/180) )   ) 
                    , 1)
                    AS distance, store_name, postal_address, latitude, longitude, phone, store_id 
                FROM stores
                ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 3";

            # Search the database for the nearest agents
            $result = mysql_query($sql);

            # run loop on locations
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo '<div class="col-sm-4 loc">';
                echo '<strong>'.$row['store_name'].'</strong><br />';
                echo ''.$row['postal_address'].'<br />';
                echo '<a href="tel:1-'.$row['phone'].'" class="ph">'.$row['phone'].'</a><br />';
                echo '<br />~ '.$row['distance'].' miles ~<br /><br />';
                echo '<input type="button" id="sendcoupon_'.$row['store_id'].'" name="sendcoupon_'.$row['store_id'].'" onclick="spc(\''.$row['store_id'].'\')" tabindex="6000" value="GET COUPON" />';
                echo '</div>';
            }

            mysql_close($link);
    }
}
else
{
    # if not zip code
    echo '<div class="col-sm-6 loc">';
    echo '<strong>You Must Input Your Zip Code and Email Address. Please Try Again!</strong><br />';
    echo '</div>';  
}


?>
```

Comment: `code: <input type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" tabindex="1000" maxlength="35" placeholder="Full Name" required >` this is how you make it required what else is neccesary

Comment: Yes however you can still click the Get My Coupon link that opens the box with available locations and submit the form.

Comment: just add the required at the end of the tag and all req fields must be inside the form

Comment: Unfortunately that doesnt work. It just highlights it red. I can still click submit. Ideally the window currently displays an error saying to enter the zip if its not. It needs to say that and email if both are not entered.

Comment: read what I have written carefully

Answer (score 1):

You can use input's "required" attribute, but it depends on browser, so better way can be check it by yourself in Javascript.

Example of "required" attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="myfield" required />
```

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp